# Wordpress plugin to redirect with notification message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, redirect

I am looking for a Wordpress plugin or simple code for cut & paste into Wordpress Post/Page. What I am looking for is to redirect a post/page in Wordpress to another URL. It must have 10 sec count down and must display this message on top of the screen or somewhere in the post. Is there one available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript, put this script between header on that page

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     var time = null;
     function move() {
          window.location = 'http://www.youdomain.com';
      }
</script>
```

apply a codition to output on body tag:

```
<body <?php if('condition')echo 'onload="timer=setTimeout(\'move()\',10000)" '?>>
<div id="mes">This page will be redirected after 10 secs.</div>
```